# Simple Html Menu in asp.net.. Broken url issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu, navigation

When I use simple menu built manually in html and css presents problem with the navigation. When I navigate a page that is inside a folder when i navigate away to somewhere outside of the current folder then the previous folder remains in the url and page not found message appears. I am currently in development stage. not deployed.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question a bit. I do not really understand the issue. Plus, for a start you could post code on how you create your menu.

Comment: I am going to take a guess and say that you are missing "~\ " in your menu / navigation but will need to see code first..

Comment: how to update the question? first tell me this.

Comment: Right under the tags in the question there is a menu with share | edit | flag.  Click edit

Comment: Thanks..using this ~\ notation does not work with the pure css html menu.. check the discussion on below answer .. plz.. problem with editing the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like you need to use absolute URLs, not relative ones. so:

http://www.blah.com/category/page.html

or just

/category/page.html

NOT

page.html

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't return to your root when you try to redirect

e.g.

I have a page called Default.aspx that isn't in a folder and a page Page.aspx in the folder called SubFolder.

Your urls probably look like this to redirect:
Default.aspx
SubFolder/Page.aspx

When you try to redirect from Page.aspx to Default.aspx, you don't return to the root, so the code will look for a page called Default.aspx in the folder SubFolder, but it doesn't exist, that's why you're getting a page not found error.

You should write your urls like this:
~/Default.aspx
~/SubFolder/Page.aspx

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is that this notation does not work in pure html and css menu... this is what is get when I return to homepage.aspx

Comment: This is the menu  <ul>
<li><a href="~/HomePage.aspx">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="~/Subject Registration.aspx">Register Subject</a></li></ul>

Comment: Oh, you might want to try this then:

../HomePage.aspx